# How to remove child controls inside Div

Tags: asp.net, html

I've a application which send the email on a particular user action. In application there is a page with a Div element like below-

```
   <div id="divResultados" runat="Server" visible="true">
       <asp:TextBox ID="firstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:TextBox ID="lastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       <asp:Calendar ID="calDOB" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Message()" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </div>
```

While sending the email I extract the `InnerHtml` text from the `Div` element and set it in the email body. The program works fine except for one issue- the receiver got the email with calendar control in expandable mode. This behaviour is not acceptable to my client and calendar control should not export in the email body.

Is there any work around?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

You can hide the calender by setting its **display:none;** on click of Button1:

```
$(function(){
  $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").on("click", function(){
    $("#<%=calDOB.ClientID%>").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On your button click event hide the calendar control and then send the email:

```
calDOB.Visible = false;
```